# Additional character while rewriting to file using FileChannel and RandonAccessFile

Tags: java, file, read-write, randomaccessfile, filechannel

I'm trying to replace existing text from a large text file using randonAccessFile and FileChannel.

This is what I have right now

```
public void updateText(final long position, final String newData) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(pathToFile, "rw");
        FileChannel inChannel = file.getChannel();
        System.out.println(newData.getBytes().length);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(newData.length());
        buf.clear();
        buf.put(newData.getBytes());
        buf.flip();
        inChannel.position(position);
        while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
            inChannel.write(buf);
        }
        inChannel.close();
        file.close();
        buf.clear();
    }
```

I'm passing these values while invoking the method

```
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 sb.append("Java is cold");
 sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 sb.append("Good job");
 updateText(14, sb.toString());



 **Input**                 **Expected Output**        **Current output**
What is this?             What is this?                What is this?
Java is cool              Java is cold                 Java is cold
Good old                  Good job                     Good jobb
Jack and Jill             Jack and Jill                Jack and Jill
```

Why am I getting additional character at the end **jobb**? I'm replacing the text with same number of characters. What am I missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I've just ran your code twice and didn't got **jobb**. Are you sure your input file isn't different?

Comment: I'm still getting extra character(Good jobb) or else sometimes the newline is removed - 
Good old becomes Good jobJack and Jill . It pulls up the next line

Comment: It appears to be a problem with your input file and not with your code. Try using a **clean** file with different sentences.

Comment: No luck. Same problem :(